# distributed tensorflow saver error

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a cpu machine and gpu machine I am using. The code is on the cpu machine. tf.train.Saver works well on the cpu machine in not distributed tensorflow. However, when I run the code under distributed tensorflow using gpu machine, it can not save.

When saving, it says not found a tempstatexxxxx file. After I added sharded=True to the saver, it only create a checkpoint file and a meta file. The file listed in checkpoint file does not exist. Then restore can not work.

What can I do?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from common import tfec2

save_dir = "/tmp"

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
step = tf.Variable(0)
step_length = tf.Variable(1)
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(save_dir)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()


with tfec2.TFEc2() as sess: # distributed

# with tf.Session() as sess:
    print ckpt
    if ckpt:
        print("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        res_obj = saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        print res_obj
    else:
        print("Created model with fresh parameters.")
        sess.run(init)
    print step.eval(session=sess)
    # print sess.run(step)
    op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    op = tf.assign(step, op_a)
    sess.run(op)
    print step.eval(session=sess)
    print("Start Save")
    saver.save(sess, save_dir+"/example.ckpt", step)
    print("End Save")
```

SOME ERROR LOG

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 78, in <module>
    saver.save(sess, save_dir+"/example.ckpt", step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1037, in save
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: /tmp/model/example.ckpt-1-00000-of-00001.tempstate3052208956008812953
     [[Node: save/save = SaveSlices[T=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](save/ShardedFilename, save/save/tensor_names, save/save/shapes_and_slices, Variable, Variable_1, bias_G209, weights_G211)]]
Caused by op u'save/save', defined at:
  File "example.py", line 34, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 832, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 496, in build
    save_tensor = self._AddShardedSaveOps(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 218, in _AddShardedSaveOps
    sharded_saves.append(self._AddSaveOps(sharded_filename, vars_to_save))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 197, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, vars_to_save)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 149, in save_op
    tensor_slices=[vs.slice_spec for vs in vars_to_save])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 172, in _save
    tensors, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 341, in _save_slices
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 661, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()







I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job saver -> {localhost:2223}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {172.31.26.237:2222}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:202] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2223
 Session Start!!!!!
model_checkpoint_path: "/tmp/model.ckpt-?????-of-00001"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/tmp/model.ckpt-?????-of-00001"

Reading model parameters from /tmp/model.ckpt-?????-of-00001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 65, in <module>
    res_obj = saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1088, in restore
    raise ValueError("Restore called with invalid save path %s" % save_path)
ValueError: Restore called with invalid save path /tmp/model.ckpt-?????-of-00001
```

### New update

(job worker is gpu machine, job saver is cou machine)

Saver works!

```
with tf.device("/job:worker"):
    # W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    step = tf.Variable(0)
    step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    # saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)


with tf.device("/job:saver"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    # b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    # step = tf.Variable(0)
    # step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    # op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    # op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)
```

But if no val in cpu machine, or saver obj in gpu machine, it does not work

```
with tf.device("/job:worker"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    step = tf.Variable(0)
    step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    # saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)


with tf.device("/job:saver"):
    # W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    # b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    # step = tf.Variable(0)
    # step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    # op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    # op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)
```

or

```
with tf.device("/job:worker"):
    # W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    step = tf.Variable(0)
    step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)


with tf.device("/job:saver"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    # b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")
    # step = tf.Variable(0)
    # step_length = tf.Variable(1)
    # op_a = tf.add(step, step_length)
    # op = tf.assign(step, op_a)

    # saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)
```

error is

```
 Session Start!!!!!
model_checkpoint_path: "/tmp/model/example.ckpt-1-?????-of-00001"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/tmp/model/example.ckpt-1-?????-of-00001"

Reading model parameters from /tmp/model/example.ckpt-1-?????-of-00001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 64, in <module>
    res_obj = saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1088, in restore
    raise ValueError("Restore called with invalid save path %s" % save_path)
ValueError: Restore called with invalid save path /tmp/model/example.ckpt-1-?????-of-00001
```

this example.ckpt-1-?????-of-00001 is on gpu machine, and in cpu mahcine there is only checkpoint and .mate file

Comment: Can you please include the full error messages that are displayed (including stack traces)?